# Why i don't have a bolt mesh in blender?

Tags: modeling

This is the tutorial i'm trying to follow: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryJ_xG3WeLw)

And in minute 9:46 is when he is adding the bolt.

I'm trying to make a tutorial and in this part he is adding a bolt:

[image: Bolt]

This is after he added the bolt:

[image: Bolt]

And this is when i make Add > Mesh...but i don't have any bolt in the menu or in the sub menus:

[image: Bolt]

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Software help can be found on other sites which you can find at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The bolt object is available from an addon that is included with blender, as it isn't showing up, that would indicate you need to enable the addon.

In *File->User Preferences* under [addons](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html), search for bolt and then enable the bolt factory addon. If you click [*Save User Settings*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings), it will be enabled every time you start blender.

[image: search for bolt factory]

When you first enable the addon you will find bolt at the bottom of the list but if you save it to always be enabled then you will find it under the default mesh objects.

Comment: Note that it is also only available in the Shift+A menu, not the Tools > Create > Mesh menu.